# Getting a specific value from a tuple within a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, tuples

I have a list like this

```
tails = {(1, 352, 368), (2, 336, 368), (3, 320, 368)}
```

where the first value is the tail number, the second is its x position and the third is its y position. Later on in my code, I have

```
for item in tail:
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, (xposition, yposition, 16, 16))
```

How do I get the second and third value from that specific tuple?

Comment: is `tails` a list or a set?

Comment: @shx2 I'm pretty sure thats a list. I'm new to this though so I could be wrong. Each tuple within tails corresponds to the x,y position of that tail segment. Later, when I draw a rectangle for each item in tail I need it to put the second value from that tuple in xposition and the third in yposition. I'm also going to be adding tuples to tails if that changes anything.

Comment: you can print `type(tails)` and find out. The way you define it in your question, it's a `set`.

Comment: @shx2 yep, it's a set. I changed it to a list because that seemed more appropriate for this. My main question though is how do I get the values from the tuples within tails. eg, if I do tails[0] it would return (1, 352, 368). However, I need to get JUST 352 or 368. so later on it would be something like pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, (SECONDVALUE, THIRDVALUE, 16, 16)) when I do for item in tails: I need it to know which one it just picked. so if it picks tails[0] it knows to get the secondvalue from that tuple not another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking to learn python basics, I'll show several different ways to do this (despite of python's "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it"):

```
for item in tails:
    xposition = item[1]  # get item by index
    yposition = item[2]
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, (xposition, yposition, 16, 16))
```

or

```
for item in tails:
    ( xposition, yposition ) = item[1:]  # tuple assignment
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, (xposition, yposition, 16, 16))
```

or

```
for tail_num, xposition, yposition in tails:  # tuple assignment in for-loop
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, (xposition, yposition, 16, 16))
```

or

```
# prepare args using list comprehension
rect_args_list = [ tuple(item[1:]) + ( 16, 16) for item in tails ]
for rect_args in rect_args_list:
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, rect_args)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm going to use the first one since it makes the most sense to me.